# The Use of Become and Became

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is  correct?

I become lazy and unproductive.

Or

I became lazy and unproductive.

Comment: That depends on what you want to say. Both _I eat fruit_ and _I ate fruit_ are grammatical, but they mean different things. Could you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the context.
For example,
if you are narrating a past experience use **became** as in

> During the vacations I **became** lazy and unproductive.

This is because you are quoting a particular time in the past when you became lazy.

But you can also use **become** to emphasize on becoming lazy as a trait that happens normally as in

> During vacations, I **become** lazy and unproductive.

Here this implies that you become lazy during **any** vacation.